# Did backup using dd break kernel update?

Tags: kernel, backup, grub

In a machine with two HDD connected to the motherboard, I used `dd` from a live USB to write the /dev/sda to /dev/sdb. After rebooting, everything seemed normal, however after an upgrade which also upgraded the kernel (`apt upgrade` on Debian), rebooting from either drive produced strange behavior. Only advanced options, and choosing the other kernel image, made a successful boot.

Why? Is this caused by GRUB? Is it correct to assume that `apt` changed something in both drives?

EDIT: the `of=/dev/sdb` is the larger drive. The installation was an encrypted cryptsetup with LVM configured with the installer defaults. So after the encrypted partitions there is free usable space, which I confirmed by partitioning and mounting it.

Comment: perhaps you now have two partitions with the same UUID?

Comment: Do sda and sdb have exactly the same size, Or sdb is larger? How is your menuentries in grub.cfg written?

Comment: It is OK to clone like you did. But *you should never boot the computer with two identical bootable drives connected* (the original one and the cloned copy). There will be confusion because of identical UUIDs of the partitions, and things will be written in an unpredictable way to either of the identical partitions. I think this is what happened and caused your problems.